# Any way to get fields from entity without actually joining into that table?

Tags: java, jpa

I'm not sure this is possible, but knowing just the very basics of JPA, I want to ask if it is possible. Basically I have an entity (We'll call it `MyEntity`) with a bunch of fields on it. We now want a 2nd entity that has all the same fields as `MyEntity` plus some of it's own. The use case for this is archiving these entities. We want to store all the archived entities in a separate table than `MyEntity` so that we don't have to qualify all the queries with `archived=false`. The JPA annotations for `MyEntity` look something like this:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="TYPE")
public abstract class MyEntity
{
    ....
```

There are multiple classes that extend this abstact class, each with `@DiscriminatorValue` annotations

For my archived entity (`MyArchivedEntity`) I want something along the lines of this:

```
@Entity
public class MyArchivedEntity
{
    private MyEntity entity;
    private String archiveSpecificField;
    ....
```

The problem with this of course is that it will want to join into the `MyEntity` table and get a specifc `MyEntity` record for populate the `entity` field. Is there some kind of annotation or something I can do to just get the same fields/columns from that entity (`MyEntity`) into this entity (`MyArchivedEntity`)?

Like I said in the beginning, I'm not sure if this is possible, but I hope I've explained well enough the end goal of what I'm trying to achieve, so that there could be some way to achieve it. If it makes any difference, I'm using PostgreSQL with EclipseLink.

Comment: What do you specifically mean by "just get the same fields/columns from that entity into this entity"?

Comment: Anyway, if use apply another level of inheritance above, jpa will qualify the queries for you.

Comment: Basically, in the DB, I want to have a table with all the same columns as the other table, plus some additional ones. We want all the archived entities in a different table from the non-archived ones. I'm not sure how another level of inheritance above accomplishes this. Can you share a specific example? Thanks.

Comment: I meant an abstract superclass with TABLE_PER_CLASS inheritance strategy for your MyEntity and MyArchivedEntity; however @ben75 answer is even a better fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is using `@MappedSuperclass` on a AbstractParentEntity becoming the super class of both `MyEntity` and `MyArchiveEntity`. So you will have something like the following:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractParentEntity {
    public String someField;
    ...
}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="TYPE")
public abstract class MyEntity extends AbstractParentEntity 
{
   //here you don't have any field (they all move to  AbstractParentEntity
   // (or, at least all the fields that need to be archivied are now declared in parent class)
   ....
}

@Entity
public class MyArchivedEntity extends AbstractParentEntity  
{
    private String archiveSpecificField;
    ....
```

More about MappedSuperclass [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance#Mapped_Superclasses):

> Mapped superclass inheritance allows inheritance to be used in the object model, when it does not exist in the data model. It is similar to table per class inheritance, but does not allow querying, persisting, or relationships to the superclass. Its' main purpose is to allow mappings information to be inherited by its' subclasses. The subclasses are responsible for defining the table, id and other information, and can modify any of the inherited mappings. A common usage of a mapped superclass is to define a common PersistentObject for your application to define common behavoir and mappings such as the id and version. A mapped superclass normally should be an abstract class. A mapped superclass is not an Entity but is instead defined though the @MappedSuperclass annotation or the `<mapped-superclass>` element.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to look into EclipseLink's history support.  It can automatically maintain a historical archive table.

See,
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/History

Another option would be to map the same classes in another persistence unit using an orm.xml to the archive tables.